# Solving a Recurrence Relation with Goats

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question says:

> Suppose that there are two goats on an island initially. The number of
>   goats on the island doubles every year. Construct a recurrence
>   relation for the number of goats on the island at the start of the
>   $n$th year, assuming that $n$ goats are removed during the $n$th year
>   for each $n≥3$.

My recurrence relation:

$a_0 = 2, a_1 = 4, a_2 = 8$ and $a_n = 2a_{n-1} - n$ for all $n \geq 3$

I am stuck on solving this recurrence relation. I was able to get $a_n = n + 2^n + 2$ for all $n \geq 2$, but I can not solve the recurrence relation for all $n \geq 0$. Is it even possible to solve this recurrence relation for all values of $n \geq 0$?

Comment: It appears that you have: You can specify $a_n$ for all $n$ as a function of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly viable to simply say: $$a_n=\begin{cases}2^{n+1} & n=0,1\\n+2^n+2 & n\ge 2.\end{cases}$$ There is no reason to require (or expect) that a given sequence should have a single arithmetic function $f$ such that $a_n=f(n)$ for all $n.$

Answer (score 2):

You are done-you have the solution, which can be written $$a_n= \begin {cases} 2^{n+1}&0 \le n \le 2 \\ 2^n+n+2 & n\ge 3 \end {cases}$$  There is no embarrassment in having cases.  When the recurrence changes it is almost guaranteed.  There are few enough you could just list the first three and leave it at that.